# How to auto-populate the <ds-select> custom library component with previously selected value?

Tags: angular

I want to pre-populate the selected value in the `<ds-select>` custom library component for an edit functionality to perform.
I have tried all possible ways, but have no idea of any predefined properties of this component that can help me to achieve this.
The HTML code is as follows.

```
<ds-select
  id="dataList"
  class="form-control"
  isMultiselect
  formControlName="dataList"
  [options]="availableData" <!-- Use the entire list as options -->
  [selectedValues]="preselectedData" <!-- Set the selected values -->
>
</ds-select
```

.ts code

```
const selectedIds = selectedValues.map(item => item.id);
this.preselectedData = availableData.map(selectedIds => selectedIds.includes(selectedIds.id.tostring()));
```

The JSON data for
selectedId

```
const selectedValues = [
  {
    "id": "42",
    "label": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "label": "fss"
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "label": "awe"
  }
];
```

availableData json

```
{
    "availableData:[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Data A",
            "desc":"Data A desc",
            
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Data B",
            "desc":"Data B desc",
            
        },
        {
            "id":10,
            "name":"Data D",
            "desc":"Data D desc",
            
        },
    ],
    
}
```

help in advance would be appreciated.